# Logic Audio: How do I create a latching toggle switch from sustain pedal data

Tags: logic, toggle, environment

Well, my problem was this, but I solved it!
I'm posting this in case this can help someone else.

I'm using Logic Pro.

I wanted to use sustain pedal midi data to toggle (latch) a button, such that I press the pedal once, and the button goes to 'ON' position. Press again and it goes 'OFF'. I wanted to use this to mute/unmute a talkback mic.

Here is my solution. If anyone can improve, go ahead!

Basic Logic ENV :
[Logic ENV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEVNw.png)

[Filter 0: (Filter out 0 values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKrol.png)

[Alt Split: (alternate pedal down instructions between 2 outputs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBKqX.png)

[Rev Pol: This generates sus pedal value 0 for every other pedal down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CobwF.png)

The object 'TALK' is just to display current state, but could be patched to anything.

Comment: please tag it with solved

Answer (score 0):

See the above images for mu own solution